# Are too many Session variables bad practice?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, session

I am thinking to use 5 session variables per user. I know if I store these variables using inproc mode it will surely affect the performance as I am having shared server.

But I am using SQL Server to store my session variables.So will it be sill overload on performance.

Because if I store variables in session my joins will be be quite simplified plus one hit to db will be saved.

Comment: I strongly advise not to store entities in the web session.

Answer (score 1):

Why not only one ? You said you are using for users, each user has an unique ID i suppose... My opinion is to use only one Session like that unique id. (Maybe you allow more account with that email or multi-account with same name, but that ID is surely unique!) .

Comment: What I am doing..every session variable is storing user different information like 
Name,Birthday,EMI,ProfilePic,Email.. in such scenarion how do I store such info in one session variable

Comment: You could create an object and save that to the session variable.  Also, take a look at ExpandoObject on msdn.

Answer (score 0):

I want to say "Yes", but it depends on what you are trying to achieve.  I have read a lot of talented developer's blogs on this topic because I have inherited older applications with lots of sessions.

I create one session per user with a unique id(guid), which is used as a key for my MemoryCache.  The guid is created after the user is authenticated.  Session is defaulted to expire after 15 minutes if idle, Cache expires after 20 minutes.  Renewal is handled for active users.  One benefit of cache is it forces the developer to create clean code (checks and balances) whereas lots of sessions can help contribute to spaghetti code.

Within my BaseController, I have a method that uses the guid to get all information saved in cache for that user.  Here is a sample and is not all the code:

**LoginController** (snippet)

```
userCache.UniqueID = GuidUtil.GenerateGuid()
userCache.UserSiteCount = userSitesList.Count
userCache.UserID = user.UserID
userCache.UserName = user.UserName
_registeredUserService.AddUserToCache(userCache)
Session("UserKey") = userCache.UniqueID
```

**BaseController**

```
    Private Function CheckAuthentication() As Boolean
        If Not Session("UserKey") Is Nothing Then
            Return True
        End If
        Return False
    End Function

    Private Function GetUserKey() As String
        Return Session("UserKey").ToString()
    End Function

    Protected ReadOnly Property GetUserInfo() As UserCache
        Get
            Return If(CheckAuthentication(), LoadUserInfo(), Nothing)
        End Get
    End Property

    Private Function LoadUserInfo() As UserCache
        Dim cachedUser = _registeredUserService.GetUserFromCache(GetUserKey())
        Return cachedUser
    End Function
```

**AllOtherControllers** (snippet)

```
Dim viewModel As New ChooseSiteViewModel
viewModel.UserSites = _registeredUserService.GetUserSites(GetUserInfo.UserID)
Return View(viewModel)
```

**ServiceLevel**

```
Function GetUserFromCache(ByVal uniqueKey As String) As UserCache _
Implements IRegisteredUserService.GetUserFromCache
    Dim userKey = String.Concat(CacheKeys.User.Main, uniqueKey)
    Return _cacheService.[Get](Of UserCache)(userKey)
End Function
```